# how to generate code based on user interaction through UI?

Tags: outsystems, appian

I'm trying to develop a software based on user interaction through UI for my use case like no code or low code platforms like `appian`, where if we drag and drop `for loop` and writing some login, it will run in the `backend`, how can I develop a software like that

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple drag and drop controls available in Appian. There are also multiple predefined templates that you can use:
[Appian patterns](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.2/component_patterns.html)

Start with [Appian Academy](https://academy.appian.com/)